# Listen asynchronously to a socket but also be able to send on socket as well in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets

I need to listen to a socket async, however I also want to be able to send data back over the same socket but I would be stuck in a while loop continuously. How do I continue to listen but be able to send data back over the socket? Here is the code i have for the async connection and listening.

```
            sock1 = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            IAsyncResult result;

            result = sock1.BeginConnect(Host1, Comm.PortInt, null, null); 

            bool success = result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(1000, true);

            if (!success)
            {
                sock1.Close();
                throw new Exception("Could not connect to " + Host);//baseDissConnects
            }


            sock1.SendTimeout = 1000;
            sock1.ReceiveTimeout = 1000;
            //sock1.Connect(Host1, Comm.PortInt);
            sock1.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReceiveBuffer, 512 * 1024);

            while (!(Console.KeyAvailable && Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)) //cool way to exit
            {
                if (IsConnected(sock1))
                {
                    if (sock1.Available > 0)
                    {
                        ProcessResponse(sock1);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Any help would be appreciated, since I not sure if I need to do this by multi-threading.

Comment: You can't.  If you are receiving asynchronously you have to send asynchronously.  The is a limitation of the Net Library.

Comment: a TCP connection has two "channels": incoming data, outgoing dat, and they are quiet independent. You just send as soon you are done receiving some data you need to respond to... Iif you are using the BeginReceive ... EndReceive patterns, then you usually will process your incoming adat within the Endreceive part and fire a BeginSend() at some time.

Comment: Ah ok so in this case everytime i send something i have to listen to what would in effect be a response. So what happens if I am sending and something is also being received at the same time. Does it get buffered and dealt with when I receive again?. The reason I ask is that it maybe better to created a send queue and do a send and receive on each iteration.

Comment: It´s rather difficult to discuss this in abstract terms, it really depends on what you are actually trying to accomplish since TCP is a flexible protocol (it allows things as different as file transfers and telnet...).